# How to import jar file (maven) into Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, android-studio

I want to import a jar file into my Android project.([here is the jar file](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids) ) 
Here are my steps:

1. Add two lines (Class-Path and Main-Class) in MANIFEST.MF file
   Class-Path: libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar 
   Main-Class:com.demos.tencent_qq_ui.Aty.MainActivity
2. Drag the jar file in the directory libs
3. Right click "Add as Library"
4. Edit my build.gradle file
        dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
       compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar') 
       }

Rebuild Project --> Run

But it occured an error : **Couldn't find or load Main Class com.demos.tencent_qq_ui.Aty.MainActivity**

I google it for a long time,but didn't get much useful info ...
Any help in catching my mistake would be greatly appreciated.Thank you!
OS: ubuntu 15.04 
IDE:Android Studio 1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.nineoldandroids</groupId>
  <artifactId>library</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I guess this could be transformed to gradle dependency like this:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
}
```

As the library is on [maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.nineoldandroids%22%20AND%20a%3A%22library%22) this should work.
I don't think you need to add anything to your MANIFEST.MF

Make sure you have mavenCentral in your build.gradle like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: If I don't add Class-Path and Main-Class to the MANIFEST.MF ,it will get another error: /libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar don't have main list  attribute [translated form Chinese]

Comment: do you have a strings.xml for chinese language? Then the problem might be that nineoldandroid library does not provide ressource strings for chinese.

Comment: I don't think so.I know lots of Chinese Developers use this library.(Maybe most of them use  eclipse instead of Android Studio).

Comment: Thank you for your time. I am going to sleep (00:53 Beijing Time).Please leave me a comment if you have any suggestions .

Comment: I have just started a new project (with intellij idea) and the only thing I added was in the dependencies block. I could sync with gradle and could build the project. When does the problem occur in your project?

Comment: when I run the project.

Comment: Nice to hear that, maybe you have "overconfigured" something in the first approach! So then you can have a good night now :P

Comment: I will check my project again,thank you for your patience.